# ASP.NET Core 6 - register a new DI at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I developed a modular system which creates a controller, a `DbContext` and a repository as an external assembly. I can load those resources at startup but what I want to do now is to load those at runtime. I could load the assemblies and I could register the controller, but I cant figure out how to register the dbcontext, and the repository to the asp.net service collection (DI) which are required for the controller.

I did this API: -- UPDATED --

```
[HttpGet("install")]
public async Task<bool> Install()
{       
    // get assembly
    var assembly = ...

    // get service types. IService is an interface I've created to mark which class is a host service
    var implementationTypes = assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract && typeof(IService).IsAssignableFrom(x));

    // add service to collection services (_service DI)
    foreach (var implementationType in implementationTypes)
    {
        // exception
        _services.ServiceCollection.AddScoped(implementationType, implementationType);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And I've created a singleton from the service provider

```
public interface IServiceCollectionProvider
{
    IServiceCollection ServiceCollection { get; }
}

public sealed class ServiceCollectionProvider : IServiceCollectionProvider
{
    public ServiceCollectionProvider(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        ServiceCollection = serviceCollection;
    }

    public IServiceCollection ServiceCollection { get; }
}
```

And registered at startup

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollectionProvider>(new ServiceCollectionProvider(builder.Services));
```

But I get an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot modify ServiceCollection after application is built.'

Comment: Are you still registering the service after `builder.Build()`? You need to move the action about Services registration before `var app = builder.Build();`.

Comment: As the exception states: the lazy registration of components during the lifetime of the application is not possible with MS.DI. In case you want to create a plug-in architecture, make sure that all plugins are loaded at application startup. There are other containers that allow registrations to be added later on, but there's typically a limit to the way in which registrations can be added.

Comment: @Chen yes, that is the idea

Comment: @Steven I understand, I thought maybe there were a way. My idea is a plugin system where once you install a new one or an update you don't need to restart the server kicking all the users.

Comment: @Santiago: If this is a hard requirement, you should investigate other DI Containers by creating POCs around them to see whether they support your exact use case. As I said, with the built-in DI Container of .NET Core (MS.DI) this can't be done.

Comment: Except... here's an idea: you can run a completely isolated DI Container instance per lazy-loaded plugin. This means that every plugin gets their own set of duplicate base registrations. But keep in mind that singleton registrations are scoped around a single container instance; in other words, each plugin will have its own singleton. Check if that's a problem.

Comment: Hi @Steven. Yes, I understand the workaround, but it might require a lot of effort, so I finally desist to use DI instead I'm instancing my services on the controller directly. For now, it's enough because is a POC.  Thanks a lot